# Ambient occlusion causes serious noises in EEVEE

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, noise-reduction, ambient-occlusion

My EEVEE render looks okay with Ambient Occlusion off:

[image]

But when I turn it on:

[image]

The noise gets really bad:

[image]

No matter how many Samples I set (it's almost as noisy in 16 samples as 1600 samples). Is this expected? If not how to fix it?